# What's the maximum safe discharge current of my sealed lead acid battery?

Tags: battery-chemistry

So I had a sealed lead acid battery which have a characteristics of 4Ah and 6v and 20h.

First if all when I searched about discharge rate of this kind of battery I found this "The sealed lead-acid battery is rated at a 5-hour (0.2) and 20-hour (0.05C) discharge".

I incidentally had a lipo battery of 7.2v 1000mAh rated at 35C which after a bit of research , it turned out that this number is the maximum safe current it can deliver so 35 * 1000 which is 35000mA or 35A.

So is this the same for lead acid battery? So for my battery I get 0.05*4000 200mA only or I mixed two different meanings together ?

Comment: you cannot determine the discharge current without knowing the load resistance

Comment: @jsotola thanks for your note I meant the maximum safe discharge current

Comment: If you have a part number you can normally check the datasheet. It should have a Max discharge current and time you can run at that max current.

Comment: @RobertFay unfortunately I couldn't open any datasheet of my battery all of the PDFs didn't open at all but it will be nice if you could know any website that has the datasheet of my battery, it is UL-Range battery named 6v4ah/20hr

Comment: You use the data sheet for the battery.

Comment: If you have reason to suspect that it's similar to other, better-documented batteries on the market, you look at several datasheets of hopefully-similar batteries.  If there's not much spread in the parameters, you cross your fingers, hold your breath, and make a guess.  Not having good data on a battery is a good reason to not design it in, unless you really need to save money.

Comment: http://www.ultracell.co.uk/products/ul-batteries/6v

Answer (score 2):

Many batteries will give you a chart in the datasheet. This is the one for a similar rated battery from Panasonic BP4-6 The Time is dependent on the current out.
[image]

Comment: So this image seems promising, but I don't know what will be the characteristics when there is a battery that have many cells like my 6v 4ah

Comment: Most are going to have several cells. The one in the datasheet has 4 cells hence the V/cell rating.

Comment: Unfortunately this table doesn't say anything about the maximum discharge current, except that 60C (the 5 minute discharge) seems to be within that maximum.

Comment: In the data sheet though it gives Max. Discharge Current 60A (5sec) for this specific battey.

Comment: @ShamsEl-Deen The characteristics of different brand SLA batteries of the same type and size are usually similar, so this chart will probably be close enough.

Answer (score 0):

If all of the information you have about the exact battery you own is the statement about how the battery is rated, then you should assume that the 5-hour rate is the maximum rate. That's 0.2C or 800mA. Note that the actual capacity of the battery **may** be significantly less than 4Ah when the discharge rate is 0.2C.

The "6v4ah/20hr" marking is not a part number so it doesn't help us to find the manufacturer's datasheet for the exact battery you have.